Intermittent SSL Error in MAUI Android using HttpClient
In MAUI Android application I'm getting a strange SSL exception that starts appearing on larger responses. The larger response is, the more probability of this exception I get. The same request could succeed after few retries.
The response is a custom binary format wrapped in a GZip stream. When the error occurs in .NET it manifests itself by a standard HttpRequestException "Error while copying content to a stream." which wraps Javax.Net.Ssl.SSLProtocolException with the following error:
Read error: ssl=0x754d4d100b98: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error 
error:1e000065:Cipher functions:OPENSSL_internal:BAD_DECRYPT (external/boringssl/src/crypto/fipsmodule/cipher/e_aes.c:1078 0x754c37dd7112:0x00000000) 
error:1000008b:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC (external/boringssl/src/ssl/tls_record.cc:294 0x754c37dd7112:0x00000000)

I've tried a few hints I found online, like

re-using HttpClient where possible (as this may be a re-use of a non-thread-safe SSL handle by internal SSL library)
using different implementations of HttpMessageHandler (HttpClientHandler/AndroidMessageHandler)
toggling HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead/ResponseHeadersRead

I've also checked on different certificates by connecting to systems where there are many Xamarin devices calling those endpoints without issues.
Would appreciate more ideas to try.

It may relate to http/2 protocol, could you have the chance to test  with http v1.1 just for problem isolation? If the application does not require explicitly, disabling client certificate based auth. on the server side may also be tested.

Will try that. Another avenue to explore is keep-alive
